# Dependency injection in JavaScript using apply, call or bind methods

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and have a question about unit-testing an object
and it's methods.  **Is using the JavaScript bind, apply and call methods
considered a form of dependency injection?**  I ask because I have several
functions I want to unit-test that use the 'this' keyword and I would like to
set the context of those functions before running a test. Should I call the
constructor with the appropriate parameters and then unit-test those methods or
could I use one of the apply, call or bind methods?  Example provided below:

```
function assert(v1, v2) {
  console.log(v1 === v2);
}

function User(firstName, lastName, identifier) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.identifier = identifier;
}

User.prototype.getUserString = function() {
  return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName + " <" + this.identifier + ">";
}

// First option:

var user = new User('Andrew', 'Schools', '09AF22');
assert(user.getUserString(), 'Schools, Andrew <09AF22>');

// Second option:

var getUserString = User.prototype.getUserString.bind({
  'lastName': 'Schools',
  'firstName': 'Andrew',
  'identifier': '09AF22'
});

assert(getUserString(), 'Schools, Andrew <09AF22>');
```

My concern with option one is that the own properties can be changed by other methods after they are invoked thus failing my tests.  I guess I could always reset the variables before every test but that's extra work, especially if the object has many own properties.  **Is there any issues with using the apply, call or bind methods when unit-testing?**

Comment: There is no [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) there.  It would be more appropriate to consider the form some form/variant of a ['mock object'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).  However, do note the issue with the bind in that it modifies *prototype-shared state* which is quite different from creating the object with the constructor params that only modifies instance state. (I say 'mock' because tests *should not test mock objects* - if there was *actually* DI then the Component would be mocked.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I guess I could always reset the variables before every test but that's extra work, especially if the object has many own properties.*

Actually this is not very difficult. For the sake of you test suite you define methods that create a set of objects and mocks for testing. And you reset your object before each test.

```
var user;
function prepare(){
    user = new User('Andrew', 'Schools', '09AF22');
}

prepare();
assert(test1);
prepare();
assert(test2);
```

That is why testing frameworks like karma, mocha have `beforeEach` methods which allows to reset environment before each unit test. Because each unit test should not depend on results of another unit test.